# Best way to deploy long-running high-compute app to GCP

Tags: gcloud

I have a python app that builds a dataset for a machine learning task on GCP.

Currently I have to start an instance of a VM that we have, and then SSH in, and run the app, which will complete in 2-24 hours depending on the size of the dataset requested.

Once the dataset is complete the VM needs to be shutdown so we don't incur additional charges.

I am looking to streamline this process as much as possible, so that we have a "1 click" or "1 command" solution, but I'm not sure the best way to go about it.

From what I've read about so far it seems like containers might be a good way to go, but I'm inexperienced with docker.

Can I setup a container that will `pip install` the latest app from our private GitHub and execute the dataset build before shutting down? How would I pass information to the container such as where to get the config file etc? It's conceivable that we will have multiple datasets being generated at the same time based on different config files.

Is there a better gcloud feature that suits our purpose more effectively than containers?

I'm struggling to get information regarding these basic questions, it seems like container tutorials are dominated by web apps.

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to have a batch-like container service that runs a container until its process completes. I'm unsure whether such a service exists. I'm most familiar with Google Cloud Platform and this provides a wealth of compute and container services. However -- to your point -- these predominantly scale by (HTTP) requests.

One possibility may be [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/) and to [trigger](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/events/pubsub-push) jobs using Cloud Pub/Sub. I see there's [async capabilities](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#http_target_tasks_with_authentication_tokens) too and this may be interesting (I've not explored).

Another runtime for you to consider is Kubernetes itself. While Kubernetes requires some overhead in having Google, AWS or Azure manage a cluster for you (I strongly recommend you don't run Kubernetes yourself) and some inertia in the capacity of the cluster's nodes vs. the needs of your jobs, as you scale the number of jobs, you will smooth these needs. A big advantage with Kubernetes is that it will scale (nodes|pods) as you need them. You tell Kubernetes to run X container jobs, it does it (and cleans-up) without much additional management on your part.

I'm biased and approach the container vs image question mostly from a perspective of defaulting to container-first. In this case, you'd receive several benefits from containerizing your solution:

- reproducible: the same image is more probable to produce the same results
- deployability: container run vs. manage OS, app stack, test for consistency etc.
- maintainable: smaller image representing your app, less work to maintain it

One (beneficial!?) workflow change if you choose to use containers is that you will need to build your images before using them. Something like Knative combines these steps but, I'd stick with doing-this-yourself initially. A common solution is to trigger builds ([Docker](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/), [GitHub Actions](https://help.github.com/en/categories/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions), [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build)) from your source code repo. Commonly you would run tests against the images that are built but you may also run your machine-learning tasks this way too.

Your containers would container only your code. When you build your container images, you would `pip install`, perhaps `pip install --requirement requirements.txt` to pull the appropriate packages. Your data (models?) are better kept separate from your code when this makes sense. When your runtime platform runs containers for you, you provide configuration information (environment variables and|or flags) to the container.

Answer (score 0):

The use of a [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) seems to better fit the bill compared to containers. [The instance always executes startup scripts as root](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#startup_script_execution), thus you can do anything you like, as the command will be executed as root.

A startup script will perform automated tasks every time your instance boots up. Startup scripts can perform many actions, such as installing software, performing updates, turning on services, and any other tasks defined in the script.

Keep in mind that a startup script cannot stop an instance but you can [stop an instance through the guest operating system](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance#stopping_an_instance_through_the_os).

This would be the ideal solution for the question you posed. This would require you to make a small change in your Python app where the Operating system shuts off when the dataset is complete.

---

Q1) Can I setup a container that will `pip install` the latest app from our private GitHub and execute the dataset build before shutting down?

A1) Medium has a great article on installing a package from a private git repo inside a container. You can execute the dataset build before shutting down.

Q2) How would I pass information to the container such as where to get the config file etc?

A2) You can use `ENV` to set an environment variable. These will be available within the container.

---

You may consider looking into [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) for more information about container.